# how to convert excel file name with timestamp into datetime format

Tags: python, datetime

I have excel file which the name has date on it something like:

20190217 - myfile.xlsx

How can I extract the date only and make it as a new variable for my dataframe using python?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime
fn = '20190217 - myfile.xlsx'
dt, _ = fn.split(' - ')
fmt = "%Y%m%d"
fmtd = datetime.strptime(dt, fmt)
df['asofdate'] = fmtd
```